# Python pandas - series to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

.

How do I print out only the country names that exist in the dataframe among series with country names as index?

Answer (score 1):

The following will filter for rows with an index value that is also in the index of `df2` using [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html).

```
df1.loc[df1.index.isin(df2.index)]
```